# Email address verification for Marketing Cloud Sender Profile

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

When you create a sender profile in Marketing Cloud, so you need to verify the email address in anyway?

I have 100 Sales Reps, and want to set each address up in Marketing Cloud as a Sender Profile, so we can send automated emails to customers and have them appear to the customer as they have come from the Sales Rep's direct email address (e.g john.smith@example.com).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [import functionality](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_from_address_and_domain_verification_configuration_checklist.htm&type=5) to verify multiple email addresses in one go:

> You can import From addresses from a data extension, or add up to 20
> addresses with a separated-by-delimiters file. Importing addresses is
> helpful for accounts that use AMPscript in sender profiles to
> dynamically populate From addresses at send time.

[image]

Or, verify the whole [sending domain](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_from_address_and_domain_verification_configuration_checklist.htm&type=5):

> Use Domain Registration to automatically verify From addresses at the
> account level. This action applies to an entire domain that is not
> part of a recommended authenticated domain via Sender Authentication
> Package or Private Domain.